# String index out of range: -21

Tags: java, string

Hello I am new in java in my code I am getting an error as String index out of range: -21
My code is

```
String targetLexForRemaining=categoryWordStr.substring(categoryWordStr.indexOf("@@")+2,categoryWordStr.indexOf(" "));
```

At this line I am getting an error?
What should I do for that?

Comment: What does `categoryWordStr` contain when you run that code?

Comment: 1) *"plz help 
Thanx in advanced"* Please use the correct spelling for words like 'you', 'your', 'please' & 'thanks.  This makes it easier for people to understand and help. 2) For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: The size of categoryWordStr is less than 21

Comment: What is the literal value of categoryWordStr  ?

Comment: check the contents of `categoryWordStr` first. is it empty? does it contain `@@` and ` `? probably not.

Comment: If you call your substring method on something like this: `String b = "(19 spaces) @@";`  You will get a -21 index out of range on it. You may want to consider `lastIndexOf(" ")`

Answer (score 10):

[IndexOutOfBoundsException](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/IndexOutOfBoundsException.html) is thrown if the `beginIndex` is negative, or `endIndex` is larger than the length of this String object, or `beginIndex` is larger than `endIndex`. Read it's [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring%28int,%20int%29).

You should check for these conditions before calling `subString` method.

```
int beginIndex=categoryWordStr.indexOf("@@");
int endIndex=categoryWordStr.indexOf(" ");

if(beginIndex!=-1 && beginIndex<=endIndex && endIndex<=categoryWordStr.length())
{
   //Call Substring
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your valuable support

Answer (score 2):

I suspect that there's a space (" ") earlier than the "@@" you're looking for, which will mess up the second argument to `substring`. If you want to get "the text between @@ and the first space" then you should use the overload of `indexOf` which takes a starting point:

```
int start = categoryWordStr.indexOf("@@");
// TODO: Validate that startisn't -1
int end = categoryWordStr.indexOf(" ", start);
// TODO: Validate that end isn't -1
String targetLexForRemaining = categoryWordStr.substring(start + 2, end);
```